# 'I ate honey at breakfast' vs. 'I had honey at breakfast'

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality

**'I ate honey at breakfast'** or **'I had honey at breakfast'**

Which is correct grammatically?

Comment: Welcome to ELL.SE. As a reminder, questions on Stack Exchange should be explicit, and demonstrate some intiial research effort— why do you think only one is grammatically correct? Have you seen or heard other examples? Without such context, this looks like a proofreading request, which is explicitly off-topic. I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for further guidance.

Comment: This isn't a question about grammar, it's a question about word choice. "I had honey" and "I ate honey" are perfectly grammatical, as are "I made honey", "I drew honey", and "I hit honey".

Answer (score 2):

Usually, we would not use either “eat” or “drink” with “honey”. We’d say “had”.

Suppose, for some reason, you were going to consume a spoonful of plain honey.

“I drank some honey” is just wrong. But we also would not say “I ate some honey”. This is because, in this situation, the honey is rarely a main ingredient. “Had” is very general. We could also use “took” - this has vague medical connotations. “What did you do for your sore throat?” “I took a spoonful of honey”.

However, if the honey is in or on something, then we would use “drink” or “eat” depending on the nature of the other thing. “I drank some tea and honey” vs. “I ate some bread and honey”.

Comment: We also have a hard time with saying "I ate some honey" because of the physical qualities of how viscous it is-- it doesn't really fit the notion of how "eating" works, but neither does it fit the notion of how "drinking" works.

Comment: That's true, although if the question asked about _pancakes_ instead of _honey_, both _ate_ and _had_ could work.